# MVC Site - Ensuring the default entry view is always correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC site with AD authorization.  This is all working fine.  I publish the site to the webserver and call the site directly (http://intranet).  If I have not logged in for a while (I have an authorised cookie with a 30 minute TTL), I am prompted to log-in and if successful I am redirected to the homeController's index view.  This is great and as expected.

If I keep the session open (browser open) and browse away from the site, if I then browse back to http://intranet, I am not challenged as I have recently authenticated but the default page is from a different controller and not the home page view.

How can I stop this from happening?  It cannot be a session setting as this is not a new session and the routes appear correct - they are not beng called at this point anyhow.

Please MVC guru's advise....!

Register route block is as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // standard MVC route regsitration

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PaginatedTimesheets",                                                 // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{view}",                                 // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Timesheets", action = "Index", page=0, view=0 }    // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with redirect

Answer (score 0):

What is your default route look like?  It should be going to your default controller/action specified in your routes.

Comment: I am sure it is correct - I have appended the RegisterRoutes method to the original comment.

Comment: Where is it going? /Home or /Timesheets? Where are you wanting it to go?

Comment: Have had to place a default.aspx, onto root, with a redirect into MVC application.  Works on localserver but not on IIS server - not hunting down issue in IIS7/.NET4.